# Low level implementation of Java Sessions

Tags: java, session

Hi I have a custom web server written for a lightweight need. Now I need the HTTP users to have session support. Any guidelines would be helpful. Note that I'm not using any servlets.

Comment: Hm, a fairly broad topic. In general you need a session tracking mechanism + server side code to manage the sessions (e.g. in memory, database, etc.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a quite compilcated thing actually, and unless its not a homework or something, this is exactly a kind of things when you should take a step back and ask yourself "do I really need a custom web server here, maybe Jetty/Windstone (just to name a couple) should be enough" :)

Today you need session, tomorrow you'll need some security stuff and voila, you have a full custom web server :)

If you want to stick to java standards you should consider interface
[HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html

Yet another source I think can help you is 
[Different Session management techniques](http://java.sys-con.com/node/37125)

I hope this helps

Comment: Awesome advice that I've been giving myself but I have no control on the decision.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly that will be a Map to hold the session data. Key is the sessionid and value could be any data structure, even another Map to hold key=value pairs.

The sessionid travels as a cookie from/to the client. So you must read the cookie from the request and send a cookie on response like here http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0092.html

Answer (score 1):

If you relatively new to the topic I recommend you to read about Session Design Pattern in the Book "Applied Java Patterns"